# android. Proguard can cause incorrect check

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard, android-obfuscation

When enable proguard then checks in my code are not working correctly. For example I have class:

```
class SomeData implements Parcelable
```

From kotlin code I check whether the passed object is SomeData (`data is SomeData`) . But the check returns me false, this not correct.
Perhaps I should add some rule to avoid this? Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that `data` is really an instance of SomeData or `data` is not null? Demo: `val data: SomeData? = null; println(when (data) { is SomeData -> "is SomeData" else -> "¯\\_( ͡❛ ︵ ͡❛)_/¯" })`

Comment: Yes I'm sure I checked it

Comment: Can you share the exact code part how you check data is SomeData? Proguard removes unused code. Is the code reachable?